# Return collection using models

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I am getting started with Sailsjs using Mongo (specifically the `sails-mongo` package and encountered an introduction problem and I cannot seem to find any documentation around this.

Basically, I have a route:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': 'PagesController.index',
  '/testing': 'PagesController.about'
}
```

Also, I have a model `Websites`

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mongodb',
  attributes: {

  }
};
```

Then inside my Controller, I do the following:

```
Websites.find().done(function(err, response){

          sails.log(response); 
});
```

Which, is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Websites.find(...).done is not a function
```

N.B. In my 'connections.js' I have the following:

```
mongodb: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 27017,
    database  : 'SEO'
}
```

Any ideas to where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple bug in your code does that.

There is no `done` function. You have to run `exec`

```
Websites.find().exec(function(err, response){

          sails.log(response); 
});
```